# pandas group by and sum with values being displayed

Tags: pandas, group-by, sum, export-to-csv

I need to group by two columns and sum the third one. My data looks like this:

```
site        industry        spent
Auto        Cars             1000
Auto        Fashion          200
Auto        Housing          100
Auto        Housing          300
Magazine    Cars             100
Magazine    Fashion          200
Magazine    Housing          300
Magazine    Housing          500
```

My code:

```
df.groupby(by=['site', 'industry'])['Revenue'].sum()
```

The output is:

```
                       spent
site        industry
Auto        Cars             1000
            Fashion          200
            Housing          400
Magazine    Cars             100
            Fashion          200
            Housing          800
```

When I convert it to csv I only get one column - spent. My desired output is the same format as the original data only the revenue needs to be summed and I need to see all the values in columns.

Comment: Try resetting the index

Comment: If you pass `index=False` in your `to_csv` or `to_excel`, then index columns will be excluded.

Comment: I did pass index=false, which gives me back all the rows, but it didn't sum up the spent column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using `as_index=False`:

```
df = df.groupby(by=['site', 'industry'], as_index=False).sum()
print(df)


       site industry  spent
0      Auto     Cars   1000
1      Auto  Fashion    200
2      Auto  Housing    400
3  Magazine     Cars    100
4  Magazine  Fashion    200
5  Magazine  Housing    800
```

Comment: Hmmm it seems like it didn' sum up spent column.

Comment: It will sum only based on the unique key of site and industry. In your example there is nothing to sum. Add one more record for 'Auto', 'Housing' and then you will see sum

Comment: You have updated the output only... not the code itself. And the code as it si - does not perform the sum...

Comment: Can you please show how you imported this data in your code?

Comment: I have rebooted everything and it works. Thanks! I have accepted the answer.